# edits in AppleScript library only work after closing and reopening Script Editor

Tags: applescript

I am writing an AppleScript library and want to test it while continuously upgrading it.

So I have two open windows in Script Editor, one for the library file and one for another script file that calls handlers from the library.

I noticed that when I add a handler to the library (or perform other changes), I can't use them in my second script file until I close the Script Editor and then reopen the files.

Is there an easier way of "reloading" the updated library?

Comment: Please share the code you have to give an good answer, even when you think it's not needed. Script Libraries can be loaded different ways and its methods have their pros and cons. Recompiling both the library and the other script would do the trick in almost any case.

Comment: Only compiling both scripts didn't work for me. I had to also save the Script Library after compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I compile and save the Script Library, then I recompile the script that uses the library, that is, I insert a return somewhere, so the source text is changed, before I recompile (cmd-K). Then I run it with the updated library. This is how it works under Mavericks. This should work with whatever kind of library you use.

Comment: I am glad it did work for you. If the answers satisfies you, then please check it off as answered. :)

Comment: I'm new here and I thought you could check it off by pressing the up arrow, and I couldn't do that yet because I don't have enough reputation. So now I learned another thing :)